# Can these concrete sewer clean out covers be safely removed

Tags: plumbing, sewer, cleanout

Located in CA. I had the sewer lateral replaced and the company put the code required clean outs in the flower bed by our front door. They also put these terrible concrete covers on top of them which aren't exactly the look we're going for with the entrance to our house. Since the flowerbed is separated there's not a risk of it getting run over by a lawnmower or anything. Is it safe to remove them and just have the black caps?

[image]

Comment: paint them .........

Comment: Are you simply looking for a more attractive cover?  There are composite covers that come in brown (or just paint per @Ruskes suggestion).

Answer (score 5):

If you remove those, the cleanouts will end up buried in the mulch. And they are not labeled. The whole point of what you have there is that they are at/slightly above grade, clearly marked as what they are, and easy to find. They also protect the plastic pipe from someone looking for them with a shovel if they do get buried over time.

Buy two flowerpots of the correct diameter to sit on top of them, or paint them to match the mulch, but don't remove them (it's probably against your sewer system's rules to remove them, as well.)

Comment: The covers may well also technically belong to the sewer company, not you.

Comment: That's almost certainly the case.